# Let $H\subset G$, for a group $G$, where for every $a\notin H$, $a^{-1}\notin H$, and $H$ is closed under $G$'s operation. Is $H\le G?$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose $H\subset G$, where $G$ is a group and H is nonempty and closed under the binary operation of $G$.

Additionally, assume $H$ has the property that if $a$ is not in $H$ then $a^{-1}$ is not in $H$.

It seems rather trivial to see the given condition: $$\left(a\notin H\implies a^{-1}\notin H\right)\iff \left(a^{-1}\in H \implies a\in H\right)$$
 by contraposition.  The latter of the two above is simply one of the hallmark conditions of a subgroup (among closure under the binary operation of $G$) i.e. there's a theorem we've proved previously in class:

Theorem: If $ab\in H$ when $a\in H$ $\land$ $b\in H$ and if $a^{-1}\in H$ when $a\in H$, then $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ assuming $G$ is a group with $\emptyset \neq H\subset G$.

Thus since in the problem we're given $H$ is closed under the operation of $G$ and is a nonempty subset of $G$, then doesn't seeing the given property's equivalence with its contrapositive as I've shown finish the proof by showing $a^{-1}\in $ when $a\in H$?

Seems too easy.

Comment: Could you please put brackets around the implications in your „condition“ :) On a first glance I dont see that your argument fails and it feels right to me...

Comment: $(p\implies q)\iff(\neg q\implies\neg p)$.

Comment: Did that make it clearer? @PrudiiArca

Comment: Yes, the argument works. Explicitly: let $a\in H$; we need to show that $a^{-1}\in H$. If $a^{-1}\in H$, you are done; if $a^{-1}\notin H$, then by the condition we have $a=(a^{-1})^{-1}\notin H$, a contradiction. Thus, $a^{-1}\in H$, as required.

Comment: It was clear to me, but missing brackets in logic freak me out :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are in the right track, but it is not just the contrapositive of the statement, so perhaps you missed a small detail.

Note that the contrapositive of "$a \not\in H$ implies $a^{-1} \not\in H$" is the following statement:

> $a^{-1} \in H$ implies $a \in H$.

With this, use $a = (a^{-1})^{-1}$ to conclude that $H$ is closed under inverses.

Answer (score 0):

No. Let G be integers mod 2, let H = {1}. The the only element not in H is 0, whose inverse is also not in H.

Edit. Did not read that H is closed.

Comment: Yeah, the lack of that condition in the title threw me at first too.